# instanceof String not behaving as expected in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to check whether a variable in an Apps Script was a String, but found that instanceof wasn't returning true when the variable was in fact a string.  The following test:

```
function test_instanceof() {
  var a = "a";
  Logger.log('"a" is ' + ((a instanceof String) ? '' : 'not ') + 'a String');
  var b = String("b");
  Logger.log('String("b") is ' + ((b instanceof String) ? '' : 'not ') + 'a String');
}
```

Logs these two messages:

```
"a" is not a String
String("b") is not a String
```

The docs aren't clear on the subset of ECMAScript that is supported, though apparently instanceof is a valid operator and String is a valid type, judging from the fact that
the code executed without an exception.

What is the appropriate way to check the type of a variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's standard EcmaScript 3.

Your code is doing what JavaScript expects: see here for the [equivalent JavaScript running in your browser](http://jsfiddle.net/yG6eC/).

Instanceof checks for a matching constructor in the prototype chain. That's good for objects created via 'new' but not very helpful for strings. What you actually want for String is typeof, as shown in [this example in your browser](http://jsfiddle.net/hA3gU/) or the equivalent Apps Script code:

```
function test_instanceof() {
  var a = "a";
  Logger.log('"a" is ' + ((typeof a == 'string') ? '' : 'not ') + 'a String');
  var b = String("b");
  Logger.log('String("b") is ' + ((typeof b == 'string') ? '' : 'not ') + 'a String');
}
```

Comment: Doh!  I've clearly been spending too much time writing Python lately, and have forgotten this detail of JavaScript.  Thanks for the refresher.