# Differences between typeof and instanceof in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, instanceof, typeof

I'm working with node.js, so this could be specific to V8.

I've always noticed some weirdness with differences between typeof and instanceof, but here is one that really bugs me:

```
var foo = 'foo';
console.log(typeof foo);

Output: "string"

console.log(foo instanceof String);

Output: false
```

What's going on there?

Comment: In JavaScript, I believe there's a dichotomy between the primitive string type and the "object" `String` type. Most of the time they're interchangeable, apparently not for the purpose of `instanceof` checks.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects

Comment: Bah, should have searched SO first:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571923/instanceof-string-not-behaving-as-expected-in-google-apps-script/11572009#11572009

Comment: take a look at this one please [http://skilldrick.co.uk](http://skilldrick.co.uk/2011/09/understanding-typeof-instanceof-and-constructor-in-javascript/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`typeof` is a construct that "returns" the primitive type of whatever you pass it.
`instanceof` tests to see if the right operand appears anywhere in the prototype chain of the left.

It is important to note that there is a huge difference between the string literal `"abc"`, and the string object `new String("abc")`. In the latter case, `typeof` will return "object" instead of "string".

Comment: Where is this "huge" difference? In current NodeJS, If I do `x = 'x'; y = new String('x')`, I can treat `x` and `y` them almost interchangeably except for a small handful of operators like `typeof`, `instanceof`, `===`. `y.constructor === x.constructor` even returns true!

Answer (score 9):

There is literal strings and there is the `String` class. They are separate, but they work seamlessly, i.e. you can still apply `String` methods to a literal string, and it will act as if the literal string was a `String` object instance.

If you explicitly create a `String` instance, it's an object, and it's an instance of the `String` class:

```
var s = new String("asdf");
console.log(typeof s);
console.log(s instanceof String);
```

Output:

```
object
true
```

Comment: You should note that `typeof` output will actually be `"object"` (a lowercase string)

Comment: @rgthree: Yes, you are right. I corrected the output.

Comment: @rgthree this should be added to answer as well