# Why is my custom exception class type losing context when an instance is thrown?

Tags: javascript, exception

My object context is not where I expect it to be.

It should be of the class type as thrown, but when caught is object.
Why is this so?
Probably something stupid. It nearly always is.

I have to use an old unknown JS runtime. It can't be upgraded so I can't use newer features, etc.

I ported the code to run in Node so it's slightly different in terms of imports and exports, but the prototypes and functions are the same. The behavior is also the same: unwanted.

This ClassA provides the test case.

```
import ClassB from "./ClassB.js"
import ExceptionC from "./ClassB.js"

export default function ClassA() {};

ClassA.prototype = {
    objB: new ClassB(),

    funcA: function() {
        try {
            this.objB.thrower();
        }
        catch (thrownFromB) {
            console.log("Caught Exception. This exception instance should be an ExceptionC. It is type:" + typeof thrownFromB);
            if (thrownFromB instanceof ExceptionC) {
                console.log("ExceptionC message: " + thrownFromB.message + "  origError: " + thrownFromB.origError);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This ClassB provides the throw and the custom exception class also.

```
export default function ClassB() {};

ClassB.prototype = {
    AugmentedException: function(errorMsg, origError) {
        Error.call(this);
        this.message = errorMsg;
        this.origError = origError;
    },

    ExceptionC: function(errorMsg, origError) {
        AugmentedException.call(this, errorMsg, origError);
    },

    thrower: function() {
        console.log("throwing a new ExceptionC");
        throw new ExceptionC("foo", "bar");
    }
};
```

This is the main function.

```
import ClassA from "./ClassA.js"

var foo = new ClassA();
foo.funcA();
```

This is the output.

```
>> OUTPUT:
>> throwing a new ExceptionC...
>> Caught Exception. This exception instance should be an ExceptionC. It is type: object
```

Comment: `import ExceptionC from "./ClassB.js"` - that's not how imports work. You're essentially importing `ClassB` (the default export) under the alias `ExceptionC`. Confirm with `console.log(ClassB === ExceptionC)`.

Comment: Neither `AugmentedException` nor `ExceptionC` should be on the prototype object of anything. You're also not referencing them properly. Given the the vague description "*losing context*", I suspect you don't understand the [difference between variables and properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572?javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues I can suspect:

1. In `ClassB.js` you use some undefined variables. Due to this, `ReferenceError` is thrown instead of `ExceptionC`. So in these lines:

   ```js
   AugmentedException.call(this, errorMsg, origError);
   // ...
   throw new ExceptionC("foo", "bar");
   ```

   you possibly mean this:

   ```js
   ClassB.prototype.AugmentedException.call(this, errorMsg, origError);
   // ...
   throw new ClassB.prototype.ExceptionC("foo", "bar");
   ```
2. In `ClassA.js` you import the same exported default class into 2 different variables. Due to this, in `ExceptionC` you actually have the same `ClassB`. So in this line:

   ```js
   import ExceptionC from "./ClassB.js"
   ```

   you possibly mean this:

   ```js
   const ExceptionC = ClassB.prototype.ExceptionC;
   ```

With these changes, I get expected:

```
throwing a new ExceptionC
Caught Exception. This exception instance should be an ExceptionC. It is type:object
ExceptionC message: foo  origError: bar
```

Comment: Thanks. I made those changes but I still don't pass the condition: ```thrownFromB instanceof ExceptionC```, it seems because ```thrownFromB``` is an ```object```, instead of an ```ExceptionC```.

Comment: @SPB Try to add `console.log(thrownFromB)` in `catch` block to be sure you catch the expected error.

Comment: Ah, yes it's ```ReferenceError: ExceptionC``` is not defined. Have to use ```this.ExceptionC``` in the ```thrower()```

Comment: So, it now essentially works but I'm confused as to why the ```typeof``` is ```object```?

Comment: `typeof` has very limited set of types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#description . For any error it returns `'object'`.

Comment: Understood after reading: ``typeof is a construct that "returns" the primitive type of whatever you pass it.`` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839656/differences-between-typeof-and-instanceof-in-javascript
Confusing behaviour for me as I can't think of another language that I've used that does this.

Comment: ```primitiveof``` would be better.

Comment: Thanks @vsemozhebuty I appreciate the solution!

Comment: @SPB Maybe you want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor instead.

Comment: @SPB I.e. try: `"It is type:" + thrownFromB.constructor.name`